# How to know if my question is appropriate for this site? And How to get attention to my question?

Tags: discussion

I posted a question  [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/19798/non-convex-quadratic-with-only-one-quadratic-constraint) . But unfortunately, it didn't get any answers. I wondered may be this question is more appropriate for math.stackexchange. But I feel it's related to site.

How can I know if a question is related to this site or not? 
And how to pose a question such that it gets attention it deserves?

Answer (score 4):

I would say it's on-topic, but this site is much smaller than math.SE so you have to have a little more patience. If you haven't had an answer within a week, you could try asking for migration. In the meantime, you can "push" your question by editing it to include more information, tags or background, but please only do it sparingly (e.g., once your question has dropped off the front page), and only when you actually have something to add (i.e., trivial edits for the sole purpose of pushing it are not OK).

In general, you can see whether a question is related by searching the site for similar (up-voted, answered) questions. If you can't find any, you can always ask on Meta as you have done.